# Scroll Behavior Broken

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

So earlier I wrote a small snippet of code to implement a smooth scroll on my webpage. Initially it was working fine, but as developing progressed it randomly stopped working and has not started working since. Now when it scrolls there is a delay from when you press the button and then eventually it snaps to the part of the page its targeting.

Here is the script tag for the library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@15.0.0/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
const scroll = new SmoothScroll('nav a[href*="#"]',{
    speed: 800
});
```

I do not want to use the CSS `scroll-behavior: smooth` because most of my sites traffic will be on Safari which doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

For browsers that do not support the scroll-behavior property, you could use JavaScript or a JavaScript library, like jQuery, to create a solution that will work for all browsers:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```